# How to pick Q elements from N sets each of size K so that I have elements from exactly P different sets (with example)

Tags: combinatorics

So let's say that I have Q = 2, N = 2, K = 2. So I want to pick 2 items from 2 sets each with 2 elements. Let's call the elements of the first set A1 and A2 and the elements of the second set A3 and A4. Now let's fix P. 
 
If P = 1, then I want to pick 2 items from 2 sets each with 2 elements and in the end I chose items from exactly P = 1 different sets. Then, the valid configurations are: (A1, A2); (A2, A1); (A3, A4); (A4, A3). 
 
If P = 2, then I want to pick 2 items from 2 sets each with 2 elements and in the end I chose items from exactly P = 2 different sets. Then, the valid configurations are: (A1, A3); (A1, A4); (A2, A3); (A2, A4); (A3, A1); (A3, A2); (A4, A1); (A4, A2). 
 
 
Can somebody help me figure out the formula for these?

Comment: If you’re looking for configurations, a general formula may be very difficult to understand intuitively at first glance, especially the indices, so it probably wouldn’t be easy to apply to particular cases.

Comment: So you are making $Q$ *ordered* picks? That is, you are picking a $Q$-element *sequence*, not a $Q$-element set?

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes.

Comment: One other clarification: Are the $N$ sets disjoint? Or can the same element be in two or more of them? For disjoint sets, there should be a not-horribly-complicated formula, but it gets much worse if they overlap.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes, they are disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to take so long to get this out. I thought I had a nice work-around for the hardest part of this when I commented, but later realized I hadn't avoided the big issue after all. I am going to convert your upper case variables to lower case, because I think it makes it easier to read.

So without a neat counting trick, the next way to handle this is with a recursion formula. One thing that can be handled easily is picking $p$ sets out of $n$. There are $\binom np$ ways of doing so, and once they are picked, there are exactly the same number of sequences that can be obtained from each. Let $F_k(p, q)$ be the number of sequences of length $q$ of distinct elements that can be picked from $p$ pairwise-disjoint sets of $k > 0$ elements each, such that the sequence contains at least one element of each set. Then the number you are looking for is $\binom np F_k(p,q)$.

There are several special cases where we can easily calculate $F_k(p,q)$ directly.

- $F_k(p,q) = 0$ when either $q < p$ or $q > pk$.
- $F_k(p,p) = p!k^p$, as there are $k$ choices for the unique element picked from each set, and $p!$ ways of ordering the resulting sequence of $p$ elements.
- $F_k(p,pk) = (pk)!$ as the sequence must use all $pk$ elements available, and there are $(pk)!$ ways for ordering it.

If we remove the last element from such a sequence of length $q+1$, there are two possibilities for the remaining sequence:

- The remaining sequence still contains an element of all $p$ sets. Thus there are $F_k(p,q)$ possible remaining sequences, and each can be completed to the $q+1$ length sequence in $pk - q$ ways, for $(pk-q)F_k(p,q)$ such sequences.
- The removed element was the only member from one of the $p$ sets. The remaining sequence contains $q$ elements from $p-1$ distinct sets of $k$ elements, including at least one element from those sets. There are $F_k(p-1,q) $ such sequences. There are $p$ sets the removed last element can come from, and $k$ elements from that set that it could be. So there are $pkF_k(p-1,q)$ sequences meeting this condition.

Putting these together, we get
$$F_k(p,q+1) = (pk-q)F_k(p,q) + pkF_k(p-1,q)$$

Note that if $q > (p-1)k$, then $F_k(p-1,q) = 0$, so for such $q, F_k(p,q+1) = (pk-q)F_k(p,q)$, and from the formula for $F_k(p,pk)$ we get
$$F_k(p,q) = \frac{(pk)!}{(pk-q)!} = \binom{pk}q q!, \quad q > (p-1)k$$

You can continue on like this. The above equations can be used to show that $$F_k(p,(p-1)k) = \left[\binom{pk}k - p\right]((p-1)k)!$$
And using the recursion formula, this expression, and the previous expression with $p$ replaced by $p-1$, you can obtain a closed formula for all $(p-2)k < q < (p-1)k$, and similarly for all remaining $q$, with each formula getting more complex each time a multiple of $k$ is passed.

Or you can forego the closed form expressions, and just use repeated application of the recursion formula to calculate vaues of $F_k$ from the known  formulas as needed.